# Making a goats cheese tart more substantial

Tags: cheese, puff-pastry

Last night I made a goats cheese tart using pesto, puff pastry, finely chopped onions, peppers and courgettes.  (Spread pastry with pesto, put veg on, break up goats cheese and bake in a 200 degree oven for about 30 mins).

It was very nice but not filling enough for a main course.

What can be added to bulk up the tart but that does not need (significant) cooking before hand  and doesnt alter the cooking of the tart too much.

Ideas include - small cubes of potato (not sure if it would cook enough), and eggs (creates more a quiche rather than a tart).

Anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: I voted to close because this is an invitation to a poll. You could add anything to the tart, and "filling" does not constrain the possible solutions to a manageably small numbers. Besides, it is subjective what you consider filling, it depends on your eating habits. There are people who can eat thousands of calories in a sitting and feel hungry if they didn't have bread.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with the close vote because it is a [What can I add to X?](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/q/1091/41) question. However I think if the question is simply more specific about "substantial", it might be workable. Maybe you can focus on a specific nutritional element (protein?) or a specific pairing (meat?).

Answer (score 1):

Eggs -- not enough to make it a quiche or custard, but enough to bind it together a bit, and give it a richer mouth-feel. I'd suggest either a single egg, or one egg + one egg yolk.

If you *do* decide on the potato, I'd cook it first -- cubed, tossed in olive oil with salt, pepper, and garlic, and roasted in a hot oven till brown. I'd use either Yukon gold or small waxy potatoes -- no russets; they're too mealy.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest a rather Zen way of bulking up the tart.

I think it would be easiest to use whole flour for the pastry instead of white flour. This will add fibre to the dish, making it more filling. It also adds a certain "rustic" flavour, in my opinion.